# How to check whether the windows system is in an input-accepting state?

Tags: c, windows

How to check whether the windows system is in an input-accepting state with c language?

For example:

- if cursor is in desktop, get 'false'
- if cursor is in a notepad title, get 'false', but in a client area, get 'true'
- if cursor is in a window text edit, get 'true'
- if cursor is in game board area get 'false, but in game chat area get 'true'
- ...

If it is detecting a certain window, we can try to capture the IME message of the window.

But if it is on an uncertain system environment (do not know what windows are open) how to determine?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: You can check if _your_ program is having focus by listening to `WM_SETFOCUS` in the wndproc. If you wish to check if _any_ program is having focus in some sub window which is accepting input, well that's very complex and far too broad a question for this site.

Comment: @IInspectable I want to simulate keyboard operation. For example, if I need to operate on a window now, if the window is inputable, I can send the character 'A' with PostMessage(Handle, WM_CHAR, 'A', 0), otherwise it is not inputable, I can send an operation that 'A' presses with PostMessage(Handle, WM_KEYDOWN, 'A', 0). I can input "A-Z, a-z, !@#$%^&*()_+" with WM_CHAR, but only can input "a-z" with WM_KEYDOWN. As long as I can check whether the system (or window) is an inputable state, I can process it differently

Comment: @Lundin em, I want to check any currently active program of the system

Comment: The system will *always* be in a state where it accepts input. The problem you have asked doesn't have a solution. The problem you are trying to solve does: [UI Automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/entry-uiauto-win32).

Comment: @lun *"that's very complex and far too broad a question for this site"* - That's a matter of setting up a [WinEvents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/what-are-winevents) hook. That's neither complex nor too broad. *"You can check if **your** program is having focus by listening to `WM_SETFOCUS` in the wndproc"* - That's correct, in 16-bit Windows. 32-bit Windows introduced an [asynchronous input model](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130604-00/?p=4173) making things far more involved. Tracking the per-thread focus is no longer sufficient.

Comment: Also, [you can't simulate keyboard input with PostMessage](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050530-11/?p=35513). I must have linked to that article close to a hundred times now. It seems it's near impossible to drive that point home.

Comment: @IInspectable Thanks, let's put aside particularly complicated situations (such as Chinese, Japanese input). PostMessage(WM_CHAR) can input upper letters and special symbols like '@', so, it makes sense to distinguish whether the application is in an inputable state

Comment: No, it doesn't. You can't simulate keyboard input with `PostMessage`. Read that again. Consider the possibility, that what you believe to be a solution simply isn't. Use UI Automation. That's what it's for. And it works with complex scripts, too.